# Iterating over an array in JSON with Play 2.1.1

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-json

I am using play 2.1.1 and I am having issues iterating through an array. I had read somewhere that you can create a reads for a List[Object] but everytime I try to do this I get an error `"No unapply function found"` for the line that says

`implicit val userListReads: Reads[List[FBUser]] = Json.reads[List[FBUser]]". The issue is " = Json.reads[List[FBUser]]`

I am at a loss of what else to try. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
def linkUsers() = Action { implicit request =>
  val json = Json.parse("{\"data\": [{\"name\": \"Me Lazyan\",\"id\": \"1182\"},{\"name\": \"Chales Dselle\",\"id\": \"10115\"},{\"name\": \"Be My\",\"id\": \"10275\"},{\"name\": \"De Rwani\", \"id\": \"11189\"},{\"name\": \"Phoe Johon\", \"id\": \"11372\"}]}")

  val peoples = json.validate[List[FBUser]].get
  peoples.foreach(println)

  Ok(json).withHeaders(CONTENT_TYPE -> "text/json")
}

case class FBUser(
  name: String,
  id: String 
)

object FBUser {
    /** Uses a Scala Macro to define the Reads function */
    implicit val userReads: Reads[FBUser] = Json.reads[FBUser]
    implicit val userListReads: Reads[List[FBUser]] = Json.reads[List[FBUser]]
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `json` value is an object with field `data` containing an array. You are trying to parse the single object as an array. You would either have to change `json` to.

```
val json = Json.parse("[{\"name\": \"Me Lazyan\",\"id\": \"1182\"},{\"name\": \"Chales Dselle\",\"id\": \"10115\"},{\"name\": \"Be My\",\"id\": \"10275\"},{\"name\": \"De Rwani\", \"id\": \"11189\"},{\"name\": \"Phoe Johon\", \"id\": \"11372\"}]")
```

or change your code to

```
val people = (json \ "data").validate[List[FBUser]].get
```

Answer (score 13):

### Purpose

Even if the the @martin's answer is giving the straight solution regarding the mismatch between the json message and the expected result, I'd like to give you some advices for a clean way to reach your goal.

That's because, AFAICK, you're redefining way too much things and you could meet cases where errors aren't reported... but just hidden by a different error like NoSuchElementException.

Lastly, I would like to give a solution where your message is kept unchanged (like the second @Martin 's solution was).

### Proposition

The idea is to keep things packaged with their responsibilities also the code is split in three different files:

`FBUser.scala` which simply declares the model structure

```
package models

case class FBUser(
    name: String,
    id: String
)
```

`formats.scala` which is a package that will gather all formats definition, specially the json ones:

```
package models

import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
import play.api.libs.json.util._
import play.api.libs.json.Json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

package formats {

  object jsons {
    implicit val fbUserFormat:Format[FBUser] = Json.format[FBUser]
  }

}
```

Note that the format for `List[FBUser]` is not provided because the json api will resolve to the implicit and generic `Reads` and `OWrites`.

And lastly, the `Application.scala` that will contain code only relevant to some use cases, like the json object containing a `data` field, the list of `FBUser`.

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json.Json._

import models._

object Application extends Controller {

  import models.formats.jsons._
  val readUserFromInput = (__ \ 'data).read[List[FBUser]]

  def index = Action {
    val jsonString = "{\"data\": [{\"name\": \"Me Lazyan\",\"id\": \"1182\"},{\"name\": \"Chales Dselle\",\"id\": \"10115\"},{\"name\": \"Be My\",\"id\": \"10275\"},{\"name\": \"De Rwani\", \"id\": \"11189\"},{\"name\": \"Phoe Johon\", \"id\": \"11372\"}]}"

    val json = Json.parse(jsonString)
    val users = json.validate(readUserFromInput)

    users.map(
      list => Ok(Json.toJson(list)) // or Ok(json) to match exactly you example
    ).recoverTotal{
      err => BadRequest(JsError.toFlatJson(err))
    }
  }

}
```

In this controller, we can see that it defines the specific `Reads` for the initial case, thus the access to the data field and the reads to `FBUser` instance are safe thanks to the use of `validate`, `map` and `recoverTotal`.

### Some words

A last note about safety, `Json.parse` is not safe so in order to be even more safe you should consider some options depending on your workflows, some of them are:
* using the json body parser that'll let you handle bad json format explicitly
* using a dedicated case class defined in the controller for this particular case (and then define its Reads/... using inception like for `FBUser`)